# В какой последовательности разблокируются несколько потоков в состояниях unique_lock?

Tags: c++, mutex, c++17

Допустим, у нас имеется несколько потоков, которые имеют доступ к некоторому разделяемому ресурсу. Контролируется он посредством std::shared_mutex (впрочем, можно обойтись и просто std::mutex). Потоки быстро обрабатывают этот ресурс и заново пытаются получить к нему доступ.

При этом одновременно может быть заблокировано на ожидание несколько потоков функциями std::unique_lock.

Как система узнает, какой поток следующий из множества заблокированных будет разблокироваться? Происходит ли отслеживание момента времени вызова lock-функции системой? Как формируется очередь разблокировки?

Если нет, то где гарантии, что при добавлении новых заблокированных потоков, какой-то из старых никогда не разблокируется?

Хотелось бы узнать, как эта механика реализована в 17 и далее стандартах.

Comment: Теоретически как раз гарантии и нет, есть такое понятие, как "голодание" - именно о том, когда взаимоблокировки нет, но можно никогда не дождаться своей очереди...

Comment: @Harry понял, есть проблема. Варианты решения? Я ранее поднимал вопрос про предоставление приоритета вызову unique_lock писателем. Разобрался, как работает алгоритм Терехова для shared_mutex. Но вот проблема - чтобы писатель прошел уровень Е1 и требуется, чтобы ему был разблокирован lock. А если есть другие заблокированные (читатели). Возвращаемся к поставленной проблеме. Может Вы что-то можете подсказать насчет приоритетного захвата ресурса писателем (1 в системе имеется) относительно многих читателей?

Comment: Стандарт не представляет никаких гарантирует по этому поводу. Всё зависит от того, что и как используется системой. Поэтому если нужен максимальный контроль, то стоит использовать примитивы системы и читать документацию к ним. P.S. хотя гарантий нет, ситуация с «тотальным голоданием» на современных ОС у Вас вряд ли случится.